# Prove $W$ is also an invariant subsapce of $\sigma^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $\sigma $ be an invertible linear transformation on linear space $V$. And $W$ is the invariant subsapce of $\sigma$. Prove $W$ is also an invariant subspace of $\sigma^{-1}$.

My try:  I was trying to prove $\sigma $ is surjective by $\sigma $ is invertible. But I forgot that $V$ may  be infinite. Then I really don't know how to do the steps. Any hints would be helpful.

Comment: If this is to work with infinite dimensional spaces, then you need to define invariant as $\sigma(W) = W$ instead of using inclusion.

Comment: @ Tobias Kildetoft So we can't prove it by the definition $\sigma(v) \in W$ for case infinite dimensional space, is it?

Comment: Exactly, since in that case we might have that $\sigma(W)$ is a proper subspace of $W$, and this implies that $\sigma^{-1}(W)$ has $W$ as a proper subspace.

Comment: @Jaqen Chou If $\sigma$ is not surjective,  what's your definition of "invertible" transformation?